# How to access the next parent element using jquery inside click method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to access the next parent element using jquery inside click method?

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(".lv1 li").click(function (event) {
    this.parentElement.parentElement.textContent = this.textContent;
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: '@Url.Action("myAction", "Mycontroler")',// MVC method: generate url for backend;
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { InitiateId: $(this).val(), InitiateType: "Discipline" },
      success: function (data) {

          $("blabla").removeClass('betimes');
          // action with data aplied on element sub2

      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
// i'm happy here
.root-head ul{list-style:none;padding:1px 1px;overflow:hidden;}.root-head ul li{display:none;}.root-head ul li.level{display:flex;float:left;color:#777;padding-left:3px;}.root-head ul li.level:before{content:" > ";}.root-head ul li.level:hover{color:#999;}.root-head ul li.level.options.betimes{display:none;}.root-head ul li.level.options .option-selector{display:none;position:absolute;top:30px;padding:10px;border:2px solid #777;border-radius:10px;width:150px;}.root-head ul li.level.options .option-selector li{display:block;text-align:center;color:#777;}.root-head ul li.level.options:hover .option-selector{display:block;}.root-head ul li.level.options:hover .option-selector li{display:block;}.root-head ul li.level.options:hover .option-selector li:hover{border-bottom:2px solid #777;color:#999;transition:linear .5s ease-in 0s;}.root-head ul li.level:first-child{padding-left:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root-head">
  <ul>
      <li class="level">main</li>
      <li class="level options">
          sub1
          <ul class="option-selector lv1">
                  <li value="1">option1</li>
                  <li value="2">option2</li>
                  <li value="3">option2</li>
                  <li value="4">option3</li>
                  <li value="5">option4</li>
                  <li value="6">option5</li>

          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes">
          sub2
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes">
          sub3
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I wont to make some changes when I press click on target element dependency by the value of the option what I chose!

How to access the next parent of the parent element?

Restriction:

I wont to be sure of it is in this block! Because of my Html structure contains this by multiple time!

Comment: [jQuery closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest) is your friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. After `$(".lv1 li").click(function (event) {` add `var a = this;`
2. Replace `$("blabla").removeClass('betimes');` to `$(a).closest('.options').next('.betimes').removeClass('betimes');`

Comment: Thank you! The solution has been useful to me, but with a few modifications: I call that before ajax calling and I stored in a variable `var obj = $(this).closest('.options').next('.betimes');` and all is it!
However, can you figure out why this phenomenon is happening?

Comment: `this` inside `click (function (event) {` and before `success: function (data) {` is the object that was clicked on. But `this` inside `success: function (data) {` changes because the context has changed.
Therefore, I offered to store the object in `a` variable before ajax calling, and you have improved this decision.

Answer (score 0):

Use `event.target.parentElement.nodeName`

List is parentElement attributes: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".lv1 li").click(function (event) {
    //event.target.parentElement.nodeName = this.textContent;
    alert(event.target.parentElement.nodeName);
  });
});
```

```css
// i'm happy here
.root-head ul{list-style:none;padding:1px 1px;overflow:hidden;}.root-head ul li{display:none;}.root-head ul li.level{display:flex;float:left;color:#777;padding-left:3px;}.root-head ul li.level:before{content:" > ";}.root-head ul li.level:hover{color:#999;}.root-head ul li.level.options.betimes{display:none;}.root-head ul li.level.options .option-selector{display:none;position:absolute;top:30px;padding:10px;border:2px solid #777;border-radius:10px;width:150px;}.root-head ul li.level.options .option-selector li{display:block;text-align:center;color:#777;}.root-head ul li.level.options:hover .option-selector{display:block;}.root-head ul li.level.options:hover .option-selector li{display:block;}.root-head ul li.level.options:hover .option-selector li:hover{border-bottom:2px solid #777;color:#999;transition:linear .5s ease-in 0s;}.root-head ul li.level:first-child{padding-left:20px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root-head">
  <ul>
      <li class="level">main</li>
      <li class="level options">
          sub1
          <ul class="option-selector lv1">
                  <li value="1">option1</li>
                  <li value="2">option2</li>
                  <li value="3">option2</li>
                  <li value="4">option3</li>
                  <li value="5">option4</li>
                  <li value="6">option5</li>

          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes">
          sub2
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes">
          sub3
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```