# How to select just the parent on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select only the element `li` with class `options` or `level` in jquery

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root-head">
  <ul>
      <li class="level" name="name1">main</li>
      <li class="level options" name="name2">
          sub1
          <ul class="option-selector lv1">
                  <li value="1">option1</li>
                  <li value="2">option2</li>
                  <li value="3">option2</li>
                  <li value="4">option3</li>
                  <li value="5">option4</li>
                  <li value="6">option5</li>

          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes" name="name3">
          sub2
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes" name="name4">
          sub3
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can make the function below called only then I click on `sub1` text, not all of the `li` element like `<li value="1">option1</li>`

```
$("li[name=name2]").click(function () {
            console.log("Funtion called");
            if (/*suplimentary condition*/) {
                console.log("Yes is here");
            }
        });
```

Maybe is useful the last my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043024/how-to-access-the-next-parent-element-using-jquery-inside-click-method)!

Comment: use  `e.stopPropagation();` onClick of `.lv1`
 `$("li[name=name2] .lv1").click(function (e) { e.stopPropagation(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stop the event propagation in the child li click event

```js
$(".level").click(function () {
    console.log("Funtion called");
});

$(".level ul").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root-head">
  <ul>
      <li class="level" name="name1">main</li>
      <li class="level options" name="name2">
          sub1
          <ul class="option-selector lv1">
                  <li value="1">option1</li>
                  <li value="2">option2</li>
                  <li value="3">option2</li>
                  <li value="4">option3</li>
                  <li value="5">option4</li>
                  <li value="6">option5</li>

          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes" name="name3">
          sub2
      </li>
      <li class="level options betimes" name="name4">
          sub3
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if `event.target` is the same as `this`.

- `event.target` will be the actually clicked element.
- `this` will be the element the click function is bound too.

According to the [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) it's a proper method of detecting event bubbling.

```js
$("li[name=name2]").click(function(e) {
  if (e.target === this) {
    console.log("sub clicked");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="root-head">
  <ul>
    <li class="level" name="name1">main</li>
    <li class="level options" name="name2">
      sub1
      <ul class="option-selector lv1">
        <li value="1">option1</li>
        <li value="2">option2</li>
        <li value="3">option2</li>
        <li value="4">option3</li>
        <li value="5">option4</li>
        <li value="6">option5</li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level options betimes" name="name3">
      sub2
    </li>
    <li class="level options betimes" name="name4">
      sub3
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

be more specific - give the target some uniqueness in the dom

```
<li class="level options" name="name2">
    <div>sub1</div>
    <ul class="option-selector lv1">
        <li value="1">option1</li>
        <li value="2">option2</li>
        <li value="3">option2</li>
        <li value="4">option3</li>
        <li value="5">option4</li>
        <li value="6">option5</li>
    </ul>
</li>


$('li[name="name2"] > div').click(function () {
    console.log("Funtion called");
    if (/*suplimentary condition*/) {
        console.log("Yes is here");
    }

});
```